# get text of element id using mouse click

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the simple question, but I am struggling with this. tried on google but every time its giving different answer..

I want id text on mouse click, eg I have table inside

```
<td>In the last month, how often have you been upset because of something that happened unexpectedly?</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" ><img id="demo1" src="cross.png" alt="" height='20' width='20' onmousedown="dis_item(this.id);" /></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" ><img id="demo2" src="cross.png" alt="" height='20' width='20' onmousedown="dis_item(this.id);"/></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" ><img id="demo3" src="cross.png" alt="" height='20' width='20' onmousedown="dis_item(this.id);"/></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" ><img id="demo4" src="cross.png" alt="" height='20' width='20' onmousedown="dis_item(this.id);"/></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><img id="demo5" src="cross.png" alt="" height='20' width='20' onmousedown="dis_item(this.id);"/></td>
```

When I click on the img its passing the id to the function of JavaScript, and I want to check which img the user has clicked, for that I need to check the id.text , so that I could compare in the function,

Here is my JavaScript code

```
function dis_item(imgId) {

  // window.alert("test");
    var text = document.getElementById(imgId).value;
    window.alert("This is Test" + text);
    document.getElementById(imgId).src = "tick.jpg";

}
```

Please advice me in JavaScript only, No jQuery please..

I want to compare which img id user has clicked.. so that I could make some calculations..

Comment: Why did you just delete all the code? Rolled it back...

Comment: Share some code. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: You could just call your function with the id string: `onmousedown="dis_item('demoX');"`

Comment: the html has no issue (see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n3L7wkeo/). check your dis_item function. look for any error in console.

Comment: Anyway like gp said your code is working fine. I''ve just tested it.

Comment: I have update the code with javascript, Please help

Comment: Thanks, i set the attribute im <img> and received in function by getAttribute(""), Its working fine now, i dont know who has answered this question, Please repost, i will mark as answer..Thanks for your help

Comment: @Aman I saw your message. It's important to not try to reply in answers. Very soon you will be able to comment. In the meantime, I'm glad I could help you. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am successful in passing the img id to the function.

An image has no "value", so this won't work:

```
var text = document.getElementById(imgId).value;
```

Instead, get some attribute in the image tag with:

```
var text = document.getElementById(imgId).getAttribute("attr");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dis_item(this.id){
if(this.id=='demo1')
   alert("Demo1");
  }
   else if(this.id=='demo2'){alert("Demo2");} `enter code here`
  } // so on
```

Comment: Perhaps try to explain your answer a little more, simply pasting code is not really informative. Nice of you to include the snippet though!